# DeviceIoControl always return fail with error code 50 (ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED)

Tags: c++, c, usb

I have small program impemented in C++. Which get information about the USB has just inserted in PC. But I have trouble with API DeviceIoControl(), it always return fail with error code 50 (ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED). My source code is as below, in which hUSB is the handle to the USB device, hUSB was success received by function CreateFile.

```
                    DWORD           dwReadSize      = 0;
                    DISK_GEOMETRY   stDiskGeometry  = {0};
                     

                    // デバイス情報取得
                    bRet = DeviceIoControl( 
                                            hUSB, 
                                            IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY, 
                                            NULL,
                                            0, 
                                            &stDiskGeometry, 
                                            sizeof( stDiskGeometry ), 
                                            &dwReadSize,
                                            NULL);
```

Comment: A have already tried with some other control code but result is same. (ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED). Please help me, thanks !

Comment: It could simply mean it isn't supported.  [This question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944239/deviceiocontrol-for-scsi-inquiry-command-returns-error-50) seems to point to using a different technique.

Comment: Documentation says: "If the operation fails or is pending, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError."  Have you tried calling `GetLastError`? Is that how you're determining the error code is `50` (`ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED`)?

Comment: @Fiddling Bits: I have already tried calling GetLastError and it returns 50. I don't know why it is not support while the device was only a USB Storage

Comment: Wrong handle, no doubt.  That IOCTL is only valid on a disk device.  You'll have to find the disk after the USB device was inserted, much the same as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24551507/17034).

Comment: @Hans Passant: Thanks, it is helpful for me

Comment: @HansPassant - nailed the vital clue again. Thanks Hans!